# turtle.tracer not working properly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I was writing code for a [CodeGolf.SE contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32134) and I came onto something I didn't understand. The code is not the best (e.g. I wouldn't normally use `while 1`) but the issue is still the same:

```
import time
from turtle import *
ht()
tracer(3)
while 1:
    clear()                     #1
    color("snow")               #
    a=time.strftime("#%H%M%S")  #
    bgcolor(a)                  #2
    write(a,0,"center")         #3
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer) it seems that `tracer(3)` means that each third screen update is drawn. I think this doesn't work, because when I run this I don't get clear text (it seems like it switches very fast between visible/invisible).

I tried with different arguments for tracer without success. I know a solution is to call `tracer(0)` instead and `update()` when needed, but I'd like it to work without `update()`.

the following does solve it, just to show what I mean. As I have understood tracer(n) should propagate the changes each n-th step, and it does not seem to do that:

```
import time
from turtle import*
tracer(0)                          #turn of auto-update
while 1:
    reset()                        
    ht()                          
    color("snow")                 
    a=time.strftime("#%H%M%S")     
    write(a,0,"center")             
    bgcolor(a)                     
    update()                        #8 propagate changes
```

Comment: You're drawing text onto a screen by sending a turtle scurrying around - how smooth did you expect it to be?

Comment: @jonrsharpe do you mean that the refreshing I see is actually the turtle drawing it? because I do not care that much about speed/efficiency, even when this method is slow. It should be possible to not see the drawing proces. (like I can with manually updateing). Also, if your theory is true, why does changing #2 with #3 not solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this with the current Python3 turtle is avoid `tracer()` and take advantage of `undo()` instead:

```
from turtle import*
import time
ht()
color("snow")
write("")
while 1:
    undo()
    a=time.strftime("#%H%M%S")
    bgcolor(a)
    write(a,0,"center")
```

It does what you want and is fewer strokes golf-wise.